# IK Handle radius in Maya

Tags: python, maya, skinning

How can I change IK Handle's radius in Autodesk Maya?

[Click to see what Radius I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQsLO.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can change it globally under: **Display > Animation > IK Handle Size...**

If you mean the "Rotation disc", then it appears to be linked to the joint size, and so can be changed with **Display > Animation > Joint Size**

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to change the size of the "Rotation disc" individually. However it only shows up when you select the IK handle, and in many cases you want to use a NURBS curve as "controller" for your rig, for an animator to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the radius of `Rotation Circle` around a `Pole Vector`.

You can only change the size of `IK Handle Display Scale`.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.ikHandleDisplayScale(20)
```